# Efficient way to parse Apache Access Log for CMS logins

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, bash, scripting, parse-server

I've been working on a way to parse large multiple access logs (sometimes in double digit GB in size) for CMSs.  Right now I just need WordPress and Joomla, but I know the types will grow over time.  Currently I have two oneliners (these will eventually go into a BASH script so any scripting language can be used as long as BASH can interpret it):

```
echo -e "\n=== WordPress ===\n"; grep --no-messages wp-login.php /usr/local/apache/domlogs/* | grep POST | grep "$(date +"%d/%b/%Y")" | cut --fields=1 --delimiter=: | sort | uniq --count | sort --reverse --numeric-sort | head | sed 's/^ *//g'

echo -e "\n=== Joomla ===\n"; grep --no-messages '/administrator/index.php' /usr/local/apache/domlogs/* | grep POST | grep "$(date +"%d/%b/%Y")" | cut --fields=1 --delimiter=: | sort | uniq --count | sort --reverse --numeric-sort | head | sed 's/^ *//g'
```

I'm trying to find a way speed these up and combine them so I only need to make one pass and then put them into separate lists.  So, for example, the output would look something like this:

```
=== WordPress ===

896 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/blogp.com
52 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/blogt.com
9 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/blog.com

=== Joomla ===

65778 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/bloge.com
478 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/blogq.com
83 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/blogh.com
```

I know there are faster parsing methods the just grep are out there, but my knowledge is very limited, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has all appearances of an [X & Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you clarify what your actual problem is, rather than how your trying to solve it?

Comment: The actual oneliners above work in their current form.  What my question is how to merge them and make it more efficient.  When running the first pass with the WordPress string, on a large number of access files, it takes a very long time to complete and then by adding another pass to search for the Joomla login it makes it go through that same long process again.  So, I'm trying to find a way to combine them into one pass and then sort out the results (see results example above) it would save time and processing power.

Comment: My thought was more along the lines of conditional logging and completely avoiding the large scale parsing of log files. E.G. `SetEnvIf Request_URI "wp-login.php$" wordpresslogin` followed by for instance `CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local1.info  -t www_wordpresslogin" combined env=wordpresslogin`.

Comment: I agree that using conditional logging would be a better option, however, in this case it wouldn't work since this would have to be done on thousands of existing servers.  That's why I would need to stick with the standard Apache access file format.

Comment: The alternative is a scripting language that allows you to efficient if-then-elseif pattern matching on the Request field of you log file. Old-school awk and perl come to mind. - Or go the route of loading them in splunk or similar.

Comment: Would you know of any good examples that I could work with?  As I mentioned my knowledge of scripting is limited.

Comment: To speed this up check for splunk (for your amound of data free maybe will be sufficient).

Comment: As I mentioned I'd like to put this into a BASH script, so I don't think that splunk would be the best option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how you configure Apache to [format your access_log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html). If you're using the common "CLF" logformat:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

Then the 7th field contains the request URL. A quick bit of `awk` which is always present and fairly efficient at parsing text. (Linux almost always has the extended [GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) as the default; on Solaris you'd better ensure `gawk`) That allows you to multiple things on a single pass:

```
awk '
   $7 ~ /wp-login.php/ {print $0 }
   $7 ~ /\/administrator\/index.php/ {print $0}
' access_log
```

will search the 7th field <kbd>$7</kbd> with the regular expression <kbd>~</kbd> enclosed by <kbd>/</kbd> forward slashes. When a match is found the <kbd>{</kbd>action<kbd>}</kbd> enclosed by the braces is performed. A simple action is `$print` the whole line <kbd>$0</kbd> that contains the match.

A slightly more complex action with updating counters in combination with an END block:

```
awk '
   $7 ~ /wp-login.php/ {++wp }
   $7 ~ /\/administrator\/index.php/ {++jl}
   END   { print wp , " WordPress Logins found.\n" , jl , " Joomla logins found.\n" }
' access_log
```

---

**Note:** Learn a proper scripting language. That is <strike>almost</strike> mandatory for a professional system administrator. The actual language is *not that important*, often a shop has an already established internal scripting standard and then you can have somebody mentor you.
A basic knowledge of `bash` `sed` and `awk` and the assorted commandline utilities in addition to grep will only get you so far. Supplement that by something like `perl`, `python`, `ruby`, even `php` or PowerShell in a Windows environment.